# Electronic boiler (water heater) stopped heating: weird cable hookup

Tags: boiler

My boiler stopped heating water yesterday. It was working fine for 1 year (I rent this home so I guess this boiler could be more than 5 yrs old.

For the debugging, I started with measuring the voltage.
I can measure 220Vac when probing pins 1 and 2.

Question 1: Shouldn't pins 1,3 be connected together? same goes for 2,4. Shouldnt they be shorted?

[image: boiler cables not connected]

On the left, the black cables go to the Red LED, which doesnt turn on.
pins 3 and 4, when probed with the multimeter I can see ~20Ac to ~60Vac, this must be voltage accumulation from stray capacitance and inductance.

Question 2: If I assume my question 1 is correct, how come both cables that short 1,3 and 2,4 are not there, even in a "melted" state?

I dont understand this electrical hookup.

Comment: 1 and 2 go into the thermostat, that brown box.  The thermostat controls what power goes to 3 and 4, and tries to prevent a runaway explosion, as what might happen if 1,3 and 2,4 were connected/shorted and the other safeties failed.

Comment: "I rent this home" sounds like you are the renter. It's up to the landlord to hire a qualified contractor to do the repair work. If that means "I rent this home to others", you should be hiring someone to do the work. It's fine to burn down your own place, but you shouldn't be burning down property owned by someone else or that someone else is living in.

Comment: @FreeMan I meant I pay the landlord rent. Its not my home. I like to do stuff my own. The landlord is a old lady, its kind of hard to find a boiler technician already, I doubt she knows how to operate a computer. I am searching for a technician to repair this, since it looks like as Ecnerwal said, needs a new thermostat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1,3 and 2,4 should not be **shorted** - that would defeat the entire point of having a **thermostat**.

If the temperature is below the current setting of 70°C they should be connected (switched on) by the thermostat. The thermostat being the brown object with the red adjuster. If they are not, that suggests that the thermostat might be bad.

*Note that it's not **inconceivable** for the actual connections inside the thermostat to be 1,4 and 2,3 even though the physical arrangement suggests that 1,3 and 2,4 is more likely.*

A standard check here is (with power supply to 1&2 shut off) to check the resistance between 3&4 - it should be some small number of Ohms, [10-20Ω for most such water-heating elements] exactly what depending on the KW rating and voltage.

But it seems most likely that the thermostat is bad and needs to be replaced.